# Prevent coersion to a single type in unlist() or c(); passing arguments to wrapper functions

Tags: r

Is there a simple way to flatten a list while retaining the original types of list constituents?..  Is there a way to programmatically construct a flattened list out of different constituent types?..

For instance, I want to create a simple wrapper for functions like `png(filename,width,height)` that would take device name, file name, and a list of options.  The naive approach would be something like

```
my.wrapper <- function(dev,name,opts) { do.call(dev,c(filename=name,opts)) }
```

or similar code with `unlist(list(...))`.  This doesn't work because `opts` gets coerced to character, and the resulting call is e.g. `png(filename,width="500",height="500")`.

If there's no straightforward way to create heterogeneous lists like that, is there a standard idiomatic way to splice arguments into functions without naming them explicitly (e.g. `do.call(dev,list(filename=name,width=opts["width"])`)?

-- Edit --

Gavin Simpson answered both questions below in his discussion about constructing wrapper functions.  Let me give a summary of the answer to the title question:

It is possible to construct a list with `c()` provided at least one of the arguments to `c()` is a list.  To wit:

```
> foo <- c("a","b"); bar <- 1:3
> c(foo,bar)
[1] "a" "b" "1" "2" "3"
> typeof(c(foo,bar)) 
[1] "character"  ## note that the result is not a list and that coercion occurred
> c(list(foo),list(bar)) ## try also c(foo,list(bar))
[[1]]     [1] "a" "b"
[[2]]     [1] 1 2 3
> typeof(c(foo,list(bar)))  
[1] "list"       ## now the result is a list, so no need to coerce to same type
> c(as.list(foo),as.list(bar)) ## this creates a flattened list, as desired
[[1]]     [1] "a"
[[2]]     [1] "b"
[[3]]     [1] 1
[[4]]     [1] 2
[[5]]     [1] 3
```

Comment: You might adjust your title to "Pass arguments in list form in wrapper function" or something like that. That's the real question in fact.

Comment: How about adding attr() to your dev object and extracting that inside your function?

Comment: You don't need to say heterogenous list - lists are, by their very nature, heterogenous.

Comment: I agree with Hadley here. You should say "heterogeneous *vector* " as that is what a list can be, just to be very clear about what is meant. Secondly, it is sufficient for just *one* of the arguments to be a list, as `c` will take the highest type of vector in it's arguments as the output type.

Comment: @Gavin: ok, I see Hadley's point now.  I edited my discussion accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as `unlist` and `c` (when applied to atomic *vectors* of different types) are creating an **atomic** vector and by definition they must be of a single type. A list in R is the most generic of vectors and you can use it, in fact the `"args"` argument of `do.call` *asks* for a list and you are supplying an atomic vector (through your use of `c()` ).

Why use `do.call` when all you are doing is generating a new device? If all you want is a wrapper to `png` that sets some defaults so you don't have to type all these out each time you want to use a `png` device, then you are being too complicated. Something like this will suffice:

```
my.png <- function(name, height = 500, width = 500, ...) {
    png(filename = name, height = height, width = width, ...)
}
```

If you want a more general wrapper, then something like:

```
my.wrapper <- function(dev, name, ...) {
    dev(filename = name, ...)
}
```

should suffice. You would use it like:

```
my.wrapper(png, "my_png.png", height = 500, width = 200, pointsize = 12)
```

or

```
my.wrapper(pdf, "my_pdf.pdf", height = 8, width = 6, version = "1.4")
```

If you want to work with `...`, you can, e.g.:

```
my.wrapper2 <- function(dev, name, ...) {
    dotargs <- list(...)
    writeLines("my.wrapper2, called with the following extra arguments:")
    print(dotargs)
    ## do nothing now...
}
```

Which gives:

```
> my.wrapper2(pdf, "foo.pdf", height = 10, width = 5, pointsize = 8, 
+             version = "1.3")
my.wrapper2, called with the following extra arguments:
$height
[1] 10

$width
[1] 5

$pointsize
[1] 8

$version
[1] "1.3"
```

So then you can programatically pull out the arguments you want and o what you want with them.

Something else that just occurred to me that might be of use is that you can use `c` to concatenate extra components on to lists:

```
> c(filename = "name", list(height = 500, width = 500))
$filename
[1] "name"

$height
[1] 500

$width
[1] 500
```

So if you really wanted to apply `do.call` to a set of arguments, then

```
my.wrapper3 <- function(dev, name, ...) {
   dotargs <- list(...)
   ## concatenate with name
   callArgs <- c(filename = name, dotargs)
   ## use do.call
   do.call(dev, args = callArgs)
}
```

But that can be more easily achieved with `my.wrapper` above.

Comment: Thanks.  Your last point answers the original question: c() _does_ create heterogeneous lists provided it's invoked on a list.  In my workspace, I already had the options as numeric vectors, which resulted in coercion.  

I think that `do.call` is a reasonable way to deal with wrappers, at least in this specific case: namely, I had several sets of {width, height} options that I stored as variables and kept swapping in and out.  This provides a clean way to do this.

Comment: @Leo; my point about 'c()' was that if you have atomic vectors of different types, it will coerce. This was what you were seeing happen, at least that is what you said in your Q. I have tried to clarify what I meant, however, as I am patently aware that `c()` can produce a heterogeneous vector when used on a list as the last part of my answer shows. The difference is a subtlety that I glossed over in the opening sentence. The part about `do.call` was garbage on my part - and I have removed it. Got it in my head `do.call` did something else.

Comment: @Leo; I still think that simple wrappers would be easier to use, but I see that the `my.wrapper3` sort of thing could be useful if you want to supply arguments stored in different lists. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 1):

```
dev <- "png"
filename <- "foo.png"
width <- 480
height <- 480
opts <- c(width=width, height=height)

my.wrapper <- function(dev,name,opts) {
  name <- list(filename=name)
  do.call(dev, c(name, opts)) 
}
my.wrapper(dev, filename, opts)
```

Note that this will work only if `opts` is a named vector, as `do.call` needs a list with named entries.

I think the reason you have to add that extra step is that `c()` does different things depending on the types of its argument - if you want a list, one of the arguments to it has to be a list, otherwise it does the necessary type conversion on all its arguments so that it can create a vector.

Comment: `opts` would need to be a named **list** if you wanted numerics, for `'height'` and `'width'` say, whilst allowing character options like `'version'` etc. If `opts` is a list, then you don't need the list call inside your wrapper.